# How to set default value of an ordering field +1 of the highest value in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Thanks in Advance. 
I have created a model in Django, in which it has a title, url and an Ordering Field. Now I have set the default value of that Ordering Field as `ZERO` . My requirement is this defult value should be changed to the `current highest Ordering number + 1`.
Ho can I do that in Admin Inteface?

```
class FooterLinks(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_("Title"), max_length=200, null = True, blank = True)
    link = models.CharField(_("Link"), max_length = 200)
    order = models.IntegerField(_("Sort Order"), default=0)
```

Comment: You're talking about [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#autofield)?

Comment: @soon can we use AutoField for this types of Purposes? They are used as primary keys, right? I mean a different field with autoincrementing, but editable and shouldn't be a unique field

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by Burhan's answer, I was able to solve a problem of mine, similar to yours.

So for your problem: In my models.py create the callable *get_new_default*

```
from django.db.models import Max

def get_new_default():
    new_order_default = FooterLinks.objects.all().aggregate(Max('order'))['order__max']+1
    return new_order_default

class FooterLinks(models.Model):
    order = models.CharField(_("Sort Order"), default = get_new_default)
```

This pastes the new maximum order value in the Text Box and keeps the field editable.

---

**---!! Edit !!---**

This raises one problem, when resetting the database, as there are no objects to calculate the maximum with. The fix is to count all the found objects and in case none exist set default to 1:

```
from django.db.models import Max

    def get_new_default():
        if FooterLinks.objects.all().count() == 0:
            new_order_default = 1
        else:
            new_order_default = FooterLinks.objects.all().aggregate(Max('order'))['order__max']+1
        return new_order_default

    class FooterLinks(models.Model):
        order = models.CharField(_("Sort Order"), default = get_new_default)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.db.models import Max
new_default = FooterLinks.objects.all().aggregate(Max('order'))['order__max']+1
FooterLinks.objects.filter(order=0).update(order=new_default)
```

To make the change permanent, either do a database migration with South; or as danihp suggested override the save method.

However note that if you table gets very large, it would be better to implement this logic as a trigger on your database.

Edit:

No, you would run this one time and it would update all the entries in your database - ideally you would do this during normal system downtime/maintenance windows.

To adjust the value in the text box, you need to update the default that you have given in your model. Note that `default` can take a value ***or a callable*** (in other words, a method). Everytime the field is rendered the method will be called.

You can use this to make sure the default is always calculated by providing a method as the default.

Comment: this will work only after saving an entry, right?
I need a the Incremented value to be in the Text Box while adding a new entry in Admin Panel? How can I do that?